# Instantiating a Class in Child constructor; accessing in Parent

Tags: php, class, inheritance

Let's say you have this code:

```
Class Dog extends Animal {
    __contruct() {
         $this->class = new self;
    }

    protected function bark() {
       echo "BARK BARK RUFF RUFF!";
    }
}
```

Then in parent `Class` you do this

```
Animal {

     protected $class

     protected function myMethod() {
         $class->bark();
     }
}
```

There might be non-related errors in this code as I just made it up on the fly; but I am talking about the main issue here.

I have code just like this in a project and I get : `Fatal error: Call to a member function <myFunction>() on a non-object ...`

Is this the proper way to access a child class from the parent like this?

**EDIT**

The real application is this:  I have a MySQL DB.  I have a parent class with generic, global functions; I have child class of it with specific table data like table names, fields, etc.  So, when I call this code,  `TableClass::myGenericSQLMethod($sql)`, that method is actually in the parent.  What I am doing is trying to instantiate is in the child's constructor and then access it in the parent.

Comment: You have $class-> bark; <-- No space is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, though that looks like just my fake code above.  No in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
class Animal {
    public function myMethod() {
        $this->bark();
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    protected function bark() {
       echo "BARK BARK RUFF RUFF!";
    }
}

$x = new Dog;
$x->myMethod();
```

That, though not a brilliant architecture by any means (in general, a parent class should not know anything about its children), does work.

---

This, however, doesn't:

```
class A {
    protected $foo;
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = new self;
    }
}
$a = new B;
```

... causing `Out of memory` error, because of the bad recursion caused by `new self` call in the constructor (as each new `new self` expression will invoke the `__construct`, starting it all again).

Comment: Ouch that is a dumb error.  Anyhow, I changed that and now: `Using $this when not in object context in`

Comment: Then I really failed to understand what you want to do. ) My point is that's not a problem to access a protected property defined on a parent within the child.

Comment: I added the real application to the question.

Comment: Well, I want to do it right (and not bring up the child in the parent class if that is bad practice).  Should I have a similarly named method in the child class that calls the parent method but adds specific info then?  If you read my application above -- assuming that is a legit use of a parent-child relationship, you see the dilemma.

Comment: Why, yes, it's quite a normal situation: child _should_ know about its parent. It might not know everything (that's what `private` properties are for), but in general, it's quite ok to call parent methods from within the children's ones (using `parent::%methodName%()` notation).

Answer (score 0):

TableClass::myGenericSQLMethod($sql) is a static method.

Assuming  in the parent you have a similarly named static method you can call it within the body of TableClass::myGenericSQLMethod as so.

```
public static function myGenericSQLMethod($sql){
parent::myGenericSQLMethod($sql);
//do other stuff
}
```

Comment: So add it to the child class and call it there?

Comment: If you added something like the above to your child class, it would call the method in the parent with the same name.. that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, it's work and the result is : BARK BARK RUFF RUFF!

```
Class Dog extends Animal {
    public function __contruct() {
         $this->class = new self;
    }

    protected function bark() {
       echo "BARK BARK RUFF RUFF!";
    }
}
//Then in parent Class you do this

class Animal {

     protected $class;
    public function user()
    {
        $this->myMethod();
    }
     protected function myMethod() {
         $this->bark();
     }
}
$an = new Dog();
$an->user();
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

It's the recommended declaration for new object.

On create new object, $this->class is directly declared as instance and to be use immediately.

PHP manual write about ;

> Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the
>   child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
>   parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
>   as private).

Also, protected function could be call only inside the same class or from parent class by extension. But really, i don't know exactly what is the real goal to write like that.